# Is it possible to execute a runnable JAR and have it run as part of the same process from which it was called?

Tags: java, process, executable-jar, jna

I have a client application and a server application. The server, using JNA, is a wrapper for some dll's I need to use because and long story short there is not enough memory to run both the client and server logic in a 32-bit JVM, hence the separate applications.

I need to be able to share memory between these two applications - specifically, I need to be able to send pointers from one to the other and vice versa. I know that I can execute the runnable JAR for the server from within the client jar - as a separate process. But is it possible to execute it as part of the same process, just on a different thread? That way I might be able to send pointers from one to the other.

Here's a bit of background:

[Sending a JNA Pointer from one Java application to another Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938760/sending-a-jna-pointer-from-one-java-application-to-another-java-application)

Comment: So you say you are using a client and a server because the address-space is too small to contain everything - and now you are asking how to have both run in the same address space. Doesn't something about this strike you as odd?

Comment: Well the client is currently running on 64-bit jvm (though it can run on either) - maybe a better question might have been is it possible for a 64-bit jar to start a 32-bit jar under the same process? I'm not exactly sure how it works. @piet.t

Comment: Don't think in terms of 32- and 64-bit jars - there is no such thing. All you are talking about is 32- and 64-bit processes/address-spaces using 32- or 64-bit dlls/sos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Sort of.

1. Create a new classloader for the JAR file.
2. Using the classloader, read the MANIFEST.MF resource and extract the name of the JAR's main class.
3. If there is a class-path attribute, parse it and create the corresponding classloaders.
4. Use the classloader(s) to load the main class.
5. Lookup the `Method` object for `main(String[])`
6. Use `Method.invoke(...)` to call it with the appropriate "command line" arguments.

The problem is that when you do this the application that you have started will share the standard i/o streams with the original one, as well as things like the system properties, default charset, default timezone and so forth.

And I don't think this is going to solve your "not enough memory" or "not enough address space" problems.

And finally, a 64 bit JVM **cannot** load 32 bit DLLs or vice versa.

---

One possible alternative might be to use shared memory:

- [Shared Memory between two JVMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396664/shared-memory-between-two-jvms)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful :)